# Angular PrimenG - Checkbox and Submit functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, primeng

I have created a component which would show the respective countries based on the city user selects using `PrimeNg`.

If user selects **London** checkbox & clicks on submit, Request should go to Backend API and fetch the country name and show on UI as : Selected city is in UK.

**Backend JSON Response :**

```
data: {
"country" : "UK",
"status" : "success"
}
```

**Project files are :**

1. **app.component.html**

```
<h5>Select City</h5>
<div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox name="group1" value="New York" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="ny"></p-checkbox>
    <label for="ny">New York</label>
</div>
<div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox name="group1" value="San Francisco" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="sf"></p-checkbox>
    <label for="sf">London</label>
</div>

<p-button label="Submit"></p-button>
```

2. **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    selectedCities: string[] = [];
    checked: boolean = false;
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

3. **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';

import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    ButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**UI Looks as below :**

[image: UI]

I am unable to figure how to store the selected city and show the corresponding country as I am new to Angular Development.

Any leads or help is highly appreciable.

Comment: If you select both, what will you show?

Comment: I want only one checkbox to be selected at a given time.

Comment: Then you need Radio Button, not checkbox.

Comment: I will have multiple cities ( more than 10) , That's why I added checkboxes. This is just an example that I tried to add.

Comment: You may have multiple cities, but you need to select just one of them. That's the main target.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**app.component.html**

```
<h5>Select City</h5>
<ng-container *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index">
  <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
    <p-radioButton name="city" [value]="city" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" id="i" (onClick)="selectedCountry = null">
    </p-radioButton>
    <label for="i">{{ city }}</label>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<br>
<p-button label="Submit" (onClick)="onSubmit()"></p-button>
<br>
<br>
<label *ngIf="selectedCountry">
  Selected city is {{ selectedCity}}<br>Selected country is {{selectedCountry}}</label>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    selectedCity: string;
    selectedCountry: string = null;
    checked: boolean = false;
    cities: string[] = [
      'New York',
      'London',
      'Delhi',
      'Mumbai',
      'Chennai',
      'Hongkong',
      'Dhaka',
    ];

    ngOnInit() {}

    onSubmit() {
      if (!this.selectedCity) {
        alert('Please select a city');
        return;
      }
      this.selectedCountry = this.getCountryName();
    }

    getCountryName() {
      // make your api call here
      // I am just mocking
      let country;
      switch(this.selectedCity) {
        case 'New York':
          country = 'USA';
          break;
        case 'London':
          country = 'UK';
          break;
        case 'Delhi':
        case 'Mumbai':
        case 'Chennai':
          country = 'India';
          break;
        case 'Hongkong':
          country = 'China';
          break;
        case 'Dhaka':
          country = 'Bangladesh';
          break;
      }
      return country;
    }
}
```

I've implemented a working demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-6-anb9ft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with radio buttons.

As I don't know your backend API. So, I've added predefined data for the demo.

See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a ton Zunayed! This was really helpful.

Comment: Hi , it will be much useful if you add extra code to your answer in case the **Stackblitz**  link change in future   

Comment: Done. @malbarmavi